# variable lists in user created functions

Tags: python

I am using python and trying to speed up the process of checking what is inside strings for a q & a program. I want to do the following for a variable amount of conditions:

```
a = input("Any question")
if "a condition" in a:
    print("the condition is in the question")
```

So here I'm checking if a condition is in a question to see what kind of question it is, and here was my idea for doing multiple conditions:

```
def ifs(a,b,c):
    b=[d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]
    while a < 8:
        b.remove(b[a])
        a = a - 1
    print("c")
```

Here, a is the number of conditions you want to check and b are the conditions being checked while c, the final, is the something to print afterwards. (c does not have anything to do with the problem). That second part `b=[d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]` is a list that is meant to be inserted where b is so you can assign a certain amount of values, which varies depending on a, which counts down to zero, as shown in `a = a - 1` removing variables one by one `b.remove(b[a])`.

I'm wondering if there's any way to be able to list off conditions without making a specifically defined command for each amount of conditions... below is what i mean:

```
def if1(a,b,c):
    if a in b:
        print(c)
def if2(a,b,c,d):
    if a in c:
        print(d)
    if b in c:
        print(d)
def if3(a,b,c,d,e):
    if a in d:
        print(e)
    if b in d:
        print(e)
    if c in d:
        print(e)
```

And so on...
Any help is appreciated, THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not pack the arguments in a list instead of writing many functions?

e.g. something like this:

```
def condition_met(condition, to_check):
    if condition in to_check:
        print(condition)

data = list(range(4))   # [0, 1, 2, 3]
condition_met(3, data)  # ok
condition_met(7, data)  # nope
```

Comment: That will do nicely THANKS